# заключить список вв строку

Tags: python, строки, list

как заключить список в строку ?

было:

```
logg = [['bot', 'pass'], ['auto', 'login']]
```

стало:

```
logg = "[['bot', 'pass'], ['auto', 'login']]"
```

Comment: str() не пробовали?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы перевести **list** в **str** подобного формата, можно просто использовать **str(list)**

```
logg = [['bot', 'pass'], ['auto', 'login']]
logg = str(logg)
print(logg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать встроенную функцию [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr):

```py
>>> logg = [['bot', 'pass'], ['auto', 'login']]
>>> repr(logg)
"[['bot', 'pass'], ['auto', 'login']]"
```